# Checking a nested hash key

Tags: ruby

I have a hash `yaml`, which is sometimes like:

```
{"foo" => {"bar" => 10}}
```

and sometimes like:

```
{"foo" => nil}
```

I want to do a certain action depending on whether `"bar"` is present.

I write this code:

```
if yaml["foo"] && yaml["foo"].key?["bar"]
...
```

I'd like to know if there's an idiomatic way to deal with that conditional, especially the first part where I have to check the existence of the parent key.

Comment: `Hash#dig` in ruby 2.3 and newer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash#`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) comes in very handy for cases like yours:

```
hash = {"foo" => {"bar" =>  { "baz" => 10}}}
hash.dig('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
#=> 10
```

Note, that if at any point of `dig`ging it returns `nil`, the method won't blow up but just return `nil` as result:

```
hash.dig('foo', 'baz')
#=> nil
```

Comment: Note that it's still possible to run into trouble with `dig` : `hash.dig('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bak')`

Comment: @yea, diggin' into integer will fail here :)

Comment: It would have been nice to have a failproof solution with `nil` as worst case.

Comment: `hash.dig('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bak') rescue nil`? :) Rubocop won't tolerate it tho

Comment: The whole point of `dig` was to avoid `rescue` and explicit logic.

Comment: I truly to say don't see why this `hash.dig('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bak')` would ever be the case in the first place. You either expect the nesting of the hash and work with it using corresponding tools or you workaround it in some other way.